# Como setar dados corretamente no Lisview?

Tags: android, listview, asynctask, assincronismo, okhttp

Galera, estou apanhando um bocado com requisição assíncrona no Android. Estou requisitando uma lista de estados em `JSON`, via `OkHttp`, e transformo em um `ArrayList` de Estados para poder setar os estados no `ListView`. Porém, de todos as maneiras que tentei a requisição só termina depois da criação do `Fragment`, sendo assim, o `ArrayList` que coloco como parâmetro do `adapter` para executar o `setListAdapter` fica vazio. Dessa forma sempre gera `NullPointerException` e eu fico sem saber o que fazer.

Vou deixar abaixo o meu último código, que já peguei de um exemplo daqui mesmo do stack, porém não obtive resultado positivo.

Como faço pra receber a requisição de forma correta? Se for Síncrona o app vai ficar travado e acredito que deva ter uma forma legal de fazer.

Segue o código.
(obs: uso uma interface para ajudar na lógica, foi a ideia que vi por aqui no stack)

**Fragment da lista de estados**

```
public class PesquisaEstado extends ListFragment implements AsyncResponse {

    private ArrayList<Estado> estados;
    private ArrayAdapter<Estado> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        new EstadosTask(this).execute();

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.item_list_pesquisa, estados);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(ArrayList<Estado> estados) {
        this.estados = estados;
    }
}
```

**Classe que extend AsyncTask**

```
public class EstadosTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Estado>>{

    public static final String URL =
            "https://bitbucket.org/Jocsa/jsonauxiliaresotb/raw/1fa827f1179ee827d1bedcdaa4c5befbe7686057/Estados.json";

    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public EstadosTask(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Estado> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setReadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Estado>>(){}.getType();
            String json = response.body().string();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<Estado> estados = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
            return estados;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Estado> estados) {
        delegate.processFinish(estados);
    }
}
```

**Interface que criei (baseado em um exemplo daqui do stack)**

```
public interface AsyncResponse {


  void processFinish(ArrayList<Estado> estados);
}
```

Ps: já fiz um debug de leve e o método `processFinish()` no `PesquisaEstado` só é executado após `onActivityCreated()`, por esse motivo que o estado fica vazio e dá `NullPointerException`.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas coisas que você terá que mudar. De início não é legal instanciar objetos sem armazena-los assim: 
`new EstadosTask(this).execute();`

O garbage collector costuma fazer muita raiva com coisas assim, principalmente assíncronas.

Outra coisa, se quiser utilizar esse tipo de adapter, é legal você tentar implementar o seu próprio `BaseAdapter`, assim você poderá chamar o formato de interface que quiser durante a listagem. Ex: Imagens, TextView, etc.

Esse `NullPointerException` está rolando por causa do  Array estados que não foi instanciado, pra inicializar o adapter você pode criar com ele vazio, mas tem que instanciar. Coloca o início mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    estados = new ArrayList<Estado>();

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.item_list_pesquisa, estados);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Isso tem que ficar no final, pois corre o risco de finalizar antes.
    EstadosTask estadosTask = new EstadosTask(this).execute();

}
```

Outra coisa é esse método `processFinish()` nele você tem que setar os dados no seu adapter, senão ele não vai atualizar.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(ArrayList<Estado> estados) {
    mAdapter.addAll(estados);
}
```

Esse tópico tem exemplos bem legais pra você seguir!
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 1):

Está dando ponteiro nulo porque você cria o `adapter` enquanto a `asynktask` está fazendo a requisição dos dados (ela executa em paralelo ao código principal, ou seja, quando você seta o `adapter` o código da `asynktask` ainda está sendo executado).

Você primeiro tem que executar a `asynktask` e **após o resultado criar o `adapter`.**

Como você sabe o que está fazendo e está usando `delegate`, então no método `processFinish` que está na `activity` (você deu implementes da interface `AsyncResponse` nessa `activity`) você vai criar o `adapter` nele.

Fluxo: executa a Asynk task -- no on result pega o `arraylist` e envia para a `activity` via `delegate` -- no método implementado, cria o `adapter` e seta os dados que estão nessa lista que você enviou para a `activity`.

Você pode até fazer uma graça e antes de executar a `asynktask` você pode setar o layout de fundo com uma animação de loading (progressbar) e depois no `delegate` você seta o layout "normal" que contenha as listas(antes de criar o `adapter`, pq se não vai dar ponteiro nulo na hora dele buscar o modelo da lista no xml).